# How to check the name of the voicechannel of the user that has connected

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am currently having trouble finding the connection status of a user and grabbing the voice channel name once the user joins the voicechannel.

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def join_party():
    guild = bot.get_guild(config.guild_id)
    voice_channel_list = guild.voice_channels
    #print(voice_channel_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) has a [`voice`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.voice) attribute, which contains a [`VoiceState`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.VoiceState) instance (or `None` if they aren't connected to a channel). `VoiceState` has a [`channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.VoiceState.channel) attribute which is the channel they are connected to.

You can get the `Member` instance of a user using [`Guild.get_member(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_member#discord.Guild.get_member).

Comment: How would i get the name of the channel of the user connected to.

Comment: My answer above already tells you how to get the channel. A `discord.VoiceChannel` has a `name` attribute that contains the name... https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.VoiceChannel.name